# Apache Hudi Serialize issue

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, serialization, pyspark, apache-hudi

Could some one please help to rectify this error
It is showing the below error when I am trying to update the data

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o84.save.
: org.apache.hudi.exception.HoodieException: hoodie only support org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer as spark.serializer

Tried sc.setSystemProperty("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer") as well.

The error is in Google data proc

Answer (score 0):

When creating the Spark Session, you can specify the config. Example

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.config('spark.serializer', 'org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer').config('spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet', 'false').getOrCreate()
```